# How to prevent foreign GET parameters in TYPO3's canonical tag?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

If an uncached page is called in the frontend with a GET parameter that is not foreseen and has been appended to the URL from a link of an external source, like a tracking parameter or something worse e.g. …

https://www.example.com/?note=any-value

… then this foreign parameter is passed on in the automatically generated canonical tag, created by TYPO3's core extension ext:seo. It looks like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/?note=any-value&amp;cHash=f2c206f6f14a424fdbf82f683e8bf383"/>
```

In addition, the page is saved in the cache with this parameter. This means that subsequent visitors will also receive this incorrect canonical tag, even if they call up the page https://www.example.com/ without the parameter.

**Is this a bug (tested on TYPO3 10.4.15) or can it be disabled for all unknown parameters by configuration?**

If you know the parameter, you can exclude it in the global configuration …

```
[FE][cacheHash][excludedParameters] = L,pk_campaign,pk_kwd,utm_source,utm_medium,…
```

… or via ext_localconf.php in the sitepackage:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cacheHash']['excludedParameters'][] = 'tlbid';
```

I am only concerned with parameters that were not expected. It might make sense to turn the concept around and basically exclude all parameters except for a few self-defined allowed parameters, but I don't know if that is possible so far.

Comment: How do you create the link? You can exclude `cHash` param in several ways, but they depends on the way you used to create the link. BTW keep in mind that [cHash is a part of caching mechanism](https://typo3.org/article/the-mysteries-of-chash) and it's added to the URL for purpose. Except of blocking it in the code (which should be very last option) the common solution is creating a route ryle for your param, which will change your custom argument into friendly URL's part like `www.domain.de/note/any-vaalue`

Comment: @biesior I don't create the link, the canonical tag is created by default by the core. Route styles are not a solution in this case either; I'm concerned about unwanted parameters that have no internal function and come from external sources (e.g. search engines).

Comment: Can you give me some sample? i.e. how are those created with *unwanted* params? Is it the page of type *link to ext page* or something else? Just checked at version 9.x and 10.x and the canonical tag in the source remain unchanged.

Comment: EDIT: I managed to recreate the case.

Comment: The unwanted parameters come from external links over which I have no control.

Comment: Yes, now I know what you mean: cleared cache + added random param in URL inputed in the address bar it produces canonical tag with cHash. I'll take a look at the source, anyway can't promise you it will be ASAP

Comment: Just tell me how do you disable cache in your case?

Comment: In my case, it was a coincidence. I had manually deleted the entire cache and a HubSpot JavaScript modified the links. A crawler then triggered the faulty links. I was able to successfully exclude the three problematic GET parameters from HubSpot via excludedParameters, so the problem is not acute. Nevertheless, I guess the concept is not optimal: i think it should not be "excludedParameters", but rather "includeParameters", where you then specify all allowed parameters.

Comment: I'm browsing the SEO's code and actually there is `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['additionalCanonicalizedUrlParameters']` which should allow that, just need to check how does it work on FE. Take a look here: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5.x/Important-86577-QueryParametersAreNowIncludedInCanonicalizedUrls.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. The extension [urlguard2](https://github.com/studiomitte/urlguard2) solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Actually, TYPO3 handles these already for other common tracking and additional params, like `L`, `utm_campaign`, `fbclid` etc. The whole list of excluded params can be found [in the source code](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php#L1380).

To add your own, just add/modify the `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` file i.e. just like:

```php
<?php

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cacheHash']['excludedParameters'][] = 'note';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cacheHash']['excludedParameters'][] = 'foo';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cacheHash']['excludedParameters'][] = 'bar';
```

or

```php
<?php

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cacheHash']['excludedParameters'] = array_merge(
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cacheHash']['excludedParameters'],
    ['note', 'foo', 'bar'],
);
```

Don't forget to clear caches after all :D (that should be a TYPO3's slogan)

Comment: The `excludedParameters` is what I meant in my last comment (below the question) ;-) Those can be edited via "Configure Installation-Wide Options" in "Settings"-Module. The problem is not to exclude known parameters, but to ensure that no faulty canonical tags are produced if for some reason parameters are appended to the URL that are not intended / which you didn't expect. Nevertheless, thank you very much for searching for the solution in the source code.

Comment: I just examined source code for this and it seems to be an only solution. If you're patient enough can try to find something yourself, I think this good point to start https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/10.4/typo3/sysext/seo/Classes/Canonical/CanonicalGenerator.php#L128 . I'm afraid it would be hard to prevent from all unknown *additions*, the best what IMHO can be done, is adding new one when they appears.

Comment: BTW next time mention what exactly you tried so we can focus on other possibilities ;)

Comment: Sorry, I should have highlighted `excludedParameters` as code in my comment to make it clearer. Thank you for your feedback - I have now revised the question and made it more specific.

Answer (score 0):

it dont work for me in the TYPO3 V11.5.16

**LocalConfig:**

[FE][cacheHash][excludedParameters] = L,tx_solr,sword_list,utm_source,utm_medi…

**Browser URL:**

```
https://www.example.org/testfaelle/test?sword_list%5B0%5D=testf%C3%A4lle&no_cache=1
```

**The HTML Frontend canonical is:**

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.org/testfaelle/test?sword_list%5B0%5D=testf%C3%A4lle&amp;cHash=e81add4ca148ad10189b9cbfa4d57100">
```

**Debugging:**
if i go in the file: "/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Utility/CanonicalizationUtility.php" and add the Parameters directly: `$paramsToExclude[] = 'sword_list';` ist works:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.org/testfaelle/test">
```

Comment: it works with: 'excludedParameters' => ['^sword_list[',],